# Magento 2 call external REST api

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, http-request

I am trying to call external api from Magento. Below is the request,

```
$client = $this->_httpClientFactory->create();
$client->setUri('thirdpartyurl.com/api/');
$client->setMethod(\Zend_Http_Client::PUT);
$client->setHeaders(\Zend_Http_Client::CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json');
$client->setHeaders('Accept','application/json');
$client->setHeaders("Authorization","Bearer 1212121212121");
$client->setParameterPost($params); //json
$response= $client->request();


return $response->getBody();
```

Always response comes as

```
Unable to read response, or response is empty
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending a PUT request I would expect a 200 request (for most REST APIs) to return NULL so it would behave as expected, did you try changing the token to see if a 400 is returning a response body ?

Comment: Even if token is changed Response is 500

Comment: Well by looking at your code I can see that the headers might be wrong so try setHeaders ( array ( "accept: application/json", "authorization: ".$apikey, "content-type: application/json", ) );  , then again I am using now magento 1.9 and curl for my API call but does Zend_Http_Client support PUT ? I would try cURL just to see if it works for your code